# Integrating an ODE with matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I've been watching David Deutsch's Lectures on Quantum Computation here

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqdVnC7OWuEcfKRZXsrooK_EPzwmWSi-N

In Lecture 2, he gives these equations to show how X,Y and Z evolve where X,Y and Z are the Pauli matrices (https://youtu.be/ajgr58WN7A4?list=PLqdVnC7OWuEcfKRZXsrooK_EPzwmWSi-N&t=1441)

Z(t+1)=X(t)

Ÿ(t +1) = Y(t)

X(t+1)=-Z(t)

In lecture 4, he explains how these equations (which are gates) came from the main physical law, the Heisenberg equation of motion, and we can get the laws above by integrating the equation from t to t+1
https://youtu.be/BmbGNtSZa1o?list=PLqdVnC7OWuEcfKRZXsrooK_EPzwmWSi-N&t=428

[This is the differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxtwR.png)

dA(t)/dt = i[H,A(t)]. with H being a special matrix and the brackets denoting a commutator

I know basic algebra and calculus but I'm a bit stuck here since there are no examples or derivations attached to the lectures. I dont know how to integrate matrices.

Both Help and resources either on the math or the theory would be great!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: He does it later for you, for time-independent *H* .